# Largest Row and Column Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Here is a program that determines the largest row and column on any given random array. 
I am not sure what the last 3 lines of code are doing.

I know they are part of the regular expression but can't seem to find a resource showing what this means "^\d,]" 
Could anyone explain what is going on in these 3 lines of code?

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix).replaceAll("[^01\]]","").replaceAll("]","\n"));
            System.out.println("Largest row index: " + rowIndices.toString().replaceAll("[^\d,]",""));
            System.out.println("Largest column index: " + colIndices.toString().replaceAll("[^\d,]",""));

```
public class LargestRowsColumnsTest {
public static void main (String[] args){
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter array size n: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int maxRowValue=0;
    int maxColValue=0;
    int [][] matrix = new int[n][n];
       for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=  rand.nextInt(100)%2;
           }
       }
    int[]rowsSum = new int[n];
    int[]colsSum = new int[n];

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
         rowsSum[i]=rowsSum[i]+matrix[i][j];
         colsSum[i]=colsSum[i]+matrix[j][i];
        }
        if(maxRowValue<rowsSum[i])maxRowValue=rowsSum[i];
        if(maxColValue<colsSum[i])maxColValue=colsSum[i];
    }

    List<Integer> rowIndices = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> colIndices = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(rowsSum[i]==maxRowValue)rowIndices.add(i);
        if(colsSum[i]==maxColValue)colIndices.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println("The random array is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix).replaceAll("[^01\\]]","").replaceAll("]","\n"));
    System.out.println("Largest row index: " + rowIndices.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d,]",""));
    System.out.println("Largest column index: " + colIndices.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d,]",""));

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`\d` is a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`), `[]` is a character group, and `^` inside character group means not.

So `[^\d]` means not a digit, or equivalent to `[^0-9]`.

In a String literal you need to escape the \.

For your reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html